# Undefined class constant 'TYPE_LIST' yii2-widget-depdrop

Tags: yii2

I'm using yii2 in local server but I face error like this

```
Undefined class constant 'TYPE_LIST'
...
...
'type' => DepDrop::TYPE_LIST
...
...
```

So, I check `vendor/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop/DepDrop.php`

There is no `const TYPE_LIST` but when I check thus file in production server there is `const TYPE_LIST = 3`

Package version is yii2-widget-depdrop 1.0.4 for both server, production and local

But when I check official package repo `https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop/blob/master/DepDrop.php`

There is no `const TYPE_LIST`

How I can fix this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is TYPE_LIST constant in the Kartik's Sortable package. Are you sure you are not mixing these two?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by mixing these two?

Comment: Like checking accidentally in another package's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to the wrong component

for depdrop the type is

> type: int the type of dropdown list to be generated. Should be one of
>   the following values:
>
> 1 or DepDrop::TYPE_DEFAULT: render a default HTML select using
>   \yii\helpers\Html::dropDownList.
>
> 2 or DepDrop::TYPE_SELECT2: render advanced Select2 using
>   \kartik\widgets\Select2 widget.
>
> If not set the type will default to 1 or DepDrop::TYPE_DEFAULT.

for sortable type is

> The Sortable widget allows you to configure the following properties:
>   type: string, the type of the sortable widget. Defaults to
>   Sortable::TYPE_LIST. Should be one of
>
> Sortable::TYPE_LIST or list
>
> Sortable::TYPE_GRID or grid

http://demos.krajee.com/sortable

http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop